# MySQL query: join these tables in order to get all tag_names used by any given `user_id` on all of his images?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider following tables structure:

```
users (user_id, ...)
images (image_id, user_id, ...)
tag_links (tag_id, image_id)
tags_names (tag_id, tag_name)
```

Let's say any given `user_id` has multiple images in the `images` table, and an image has multiple tags stored in `tag_links`.

How can I join these tables in order to get all tag_names used by any given `user_id` on all of his images? Are these kind of queries (joing multiple tables) slow and not recommended, or is it common to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Joining is common and it's the way it should be done.

```
SELECT tn.tag_name
FROM tags_names AS tn
INNER JOIN tag_links AS tl ON tn.tag_id=tl.tag_id
INNER JOIN images AS i ON tl.image_id=i.image_id
WHERE i.user_id=YOURUSERID
```

Your table design though only makes sense if a tag can have more then one name, if not use a column `name` on `tag_links`.

Comment: +1. If the query doesn't need anything from the users table (e.g. UserName etc) then you can skip the join to table users. You might also need to DISTINCT the tag names if you want to remove duplicate tags.

Comment: @cularis thanks really, but as you said my design makes sense only if a tag can have more than one name, otherwise i should add a column in tag_links. Did you mean that the tag_names is not required instead i should have tag_links table with three columns: tag_id, tag_name and image_id. But my idea is that since a tag (eg. "java") can be used on different images. So if i have only one table, i will need to add new row for the same tag for each image. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if you can have more than one tag_name per tag_links, but if you can, your table design is correct.